# How to efficiently store sql in a PHP application?

Tags: php, mysql, function, switch-statement, memory-efficient

I have an application that has a lot of queries that are reused in multiple places. What is the most efficient way to store these? My instinct is to store them in an array in a class, ie:

```
$sql['report 1'] = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE expression";
$sql['report 2'] = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE expression2";
```

etc.

Another developer who had worked on this project did it using switch case:

```
switch($query){
    case 'report 1': 
        $sql = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE expression1";
        break;
    case 'report 2':
        $sql = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE expression2";
        break;
 }
 $result = runquery($sql);
```

Another idea I had was that each report should be a function of its own:

```
function report1(){
    // run the query here
    return result;
}
function report2(){
    // run the query here
    return $result;
}
```

I prefer the array method because it seems like cleaner code, but since there are a large number of queries, isn't this wasteful in terms of memory use? Wouldn't all queries end up stored in memory?

The switch case method seems a little unwieldy. What are the up and downsides of these methods? Is there a method that stands out the "the best way" to do this? Or perhaps another method I haven't considered?

Comment: Don't "store" SQL queries. Define them in one place and call that function.

Comment: Honestly, I also have a lot of queries which get run and I don't save them anywhere. I am writing them harcoded with a querybuilder class. E.g. `$sql = querybuilder::newInstance()->table('settings')->select("*"); //returns the PDOStatement object`. This seems like it's a waste of disk space, but what if you wanna get more specified or different data from that table, will you add now another function? I'll just add more methods to the list above (or other developers will just extend the sql string). Honestly I don't see the pro of using an array, switch or function to just return sql data.

Comment: I agree with @juergen. The best way is to have a repository class where you have methods like: `public function getReport1()` which contain the SQL-query and fetches the results. Then it's easy to swap the repository-class with dependency injection etc. for testing/changing storage.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this question a long time ago. The pain point that drove us to resolve this question was that we were seeing a lot of duplication in SQL queries littered throughout the code.

We had our own home-grown MVC framework, and we had simple wrapper classes for database access, but we regularly found the same SQL query in multiple model classes.

We felt at the time that it was not necessary to factor out the SQL into separate functions in a data access layer - this would be cleaner, but it would introduce a whole new "layer" into the architecture, and that additional layer of complexity was not necessary. We also didn't want to re-work the model classes to be more granular - we were under a lot of time pressure, and the team felt the basic structure wasn't causing any pain - it was just the duplication of SQL queries which hurt.

Our solution was pretty basic. We created a PHP file with variables for each query (it wasn't an array as you describe, just one variable per query). We used the uppercase notation convention to indicate it was "constant". We liberally littered the SQL file with comments and used a naming convention to help developers understand the intent, not the mechanic. Something like:

```
$REPORT1_GET_THIS_FOR_EXPRESSION = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE expression";
$REPORT2_GET_THIS_FOR_EXPRESSION2 = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE expression2";
```

We included this PHP file in all the model classes. Yes, it takes up memory, but not so as you'd notice - in fact, memory usage was probably lower because those same strings weren't duplicated in other source files at run time.

This worked fine for our (small-ish) project, with 3 or so developers, all working together in the same room. Our boss valued time to market over maintainability or extensibility, and this worked pretty well. The code was readable, and we could change a SQL query in one place and fix lots of bugs.

I wouldn't use the "switch" statement solution. Each SQL statement is 3 lines of code (as opposed to one line of code), and involves a logic statement which can go wrong ([cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) would be through the roof). In my experience, less code is nearly always better...